# SEDE query for questions that have positive scores but get at least one downvote and vice versa

Tags: support, questions, data-explorer

I require to find the number (or percentage) of questions that have a positive score but received at least one downvote. I think this finding also help to find the alternative case i.e. negative score with an upvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1019831/number-of-questions-with-a-positive-score-and-at-least-one-downvote), 593947 Stack Overflow questions have a positive score and at least one downvote. You can use the site switcher below the query to run it for other sites. Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1019831) the query for other investigations.

Note that SEDE is updated each Sunday morning, so actual numbers might be a little bit higher. It doesn't include deleted questions (which might be relevant for negatively scoring questions with upvotes). If you're new to SQL and/or SEDE, don't forget to take the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).